# How to get OnChange Event of Telerik DatePicker

Tags: telerik

I want to show updated date in alert on OnChange event of Telerik DatePicker. Here is my code: `@Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(model => model.HarvestDate).ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange("javascript:alert('On Change');"))`.

AND

```
 @(Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(x => x.HarvestDate).InputHtmlAttributes(new { onChange = "javascript:alert('On Change');"}))
```

Both of these scenarios does not firing onChange event. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
@(Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(model => model.HarvestDate)
        .Name("DatePicker")
        .ClientEvents(events => events
               .OnChange("OnChange")
        )
)
<script>
function OnChange(e) {
    alert("On Change");
}
</script>
```